# Accessing URL params in "href" when using "as" for Next Link?

Tags: next.js

I have a `Link` where I want to pass certain params in the URL but I don't want the browser to display the params.

I'm using `Link`'s `as` for this:

```
<Link href={`/link?foo=bar`} as ={`/link`}>
  <a>Link</a>
</Link>
```

But when I click this link and I try to access the params via router, I can't access `foo=bar`:

```
const router = useRouter()
console.log(router.query)
```

Returns

```
{
  slug: ["link"],
}
```

And not

```
{
  slug: ["link"],
  foo: "bar",
}
```

So how can I access the URL params in `href` when using `as` for `Link`?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** You can't use `as` like that.

This is an incorrect usage of `href` and `as`. It would be cool if we could hide state from the end users to keep our URLs nice, clean, and compact, but obviously if you do that, you'll actually lose the state when copy/pasting the URL. That's why you can't hide query parameters in anyway (except for excluding them).

Here's the docs on `href` and `as` (dynamic routes, has little to do with hiding query params):

https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes

And to further bring up my point, imagine if we could hide state, and we redirect to this URL:

```
https://example.com/stateful/
```

Presumably there would be some behind-the-scenes browser action that persists the state.

Now we copy/paste the URL:

```
https://example.com/stateful/
```

Oops! We don't have the state anymore because the browser has no previous state to keep track of! That's why you use query parameters, because they keep the state in the URL itself.