# query props lost when refreshing page in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in my Next js app I'm routing through pages and passing props with the Link query. and the page switch perfectly but when reloading page all props gets lost.

card.js

```
<Link href={{
          pathname: "/TvShows",
          query: {
              result: result,
              img: img,
              index: index
          }}}
          as={`TvShows/?${title}`}
          >
```

and in TvShows.js

```
const TvShows = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();
  const query = router.query;

  useEffect (()=>{
    if(router.isReady){
      console.log(result);
      setResult(query.result);
      setIndex(query.index);
      setImg(query.img);
    }
  },[router.isReady])
  
  return (
    <div className=''>
        <Background result={result} img={img} index={index} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TvShows
```

why is this happening? and what is the fix for this?

Comment: what do you mean with the query props are lost? if you're using `as` they will be lost because the url should have the query `?img=&result=&index` to be able to use them on refresh

Comment: @mocherfaoui Thanks it worked when i removed it. but if you don't mind me asking when is the `as` get used

Comment: short answer it won't work in this case, if you want to read more on that this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71390369/18457414